# Serial port outputs old value upon manual PRINT command

Tags: serial-port, compact-framework2.0

I have an app that is connected to the balance through the serial port. The balance is quite large and pressing the PRINT button is not an option. So my app asks the balance to print programmatically upon a certain user action. The balance interface allows it, and defines a print command. All works for awhile. Then after weighting few items, the balance starts outputing the previous weight....I am buffled at this point since there are few commands defined and there is not too many options to what can be done. I am already flushing out the OUT buffer after each time. So I don't know why it keeps giving me the old value.

Here is my code:

```
        if (askedToPrint)
        {
                _sp.DiscardOutBuffer();

                //ask the balance to print
                _sp.Write("P\r\n");

         }
```

_sp - is a SerialPort object

I am using WinCE 6.0 and Compact Framework 2.0/C#

Answer (score 0):

if you are reading data from serial port using Readline() or Read() then there is a possibility that balance have sent multiple packets queued. So before reading you have to discard already pending packets. other way around is before writing request to print use ReadExisting() method to read all available data. So after sending command if your balance still sending old packets then there might be a problem with balance.